# Windows program for photo slideshow

Tags: windows, gratis, slideshow

Looking for very simple program to present pictures as slideshow.

I would use Windows built in photo viewing app, but I need to extend picture change time and also I need to show pictures in random order. But seems that such features are not available in Windows.

Hopefully someone could recommend some free program, what will be able to present pictures from certain folder as slideshow in random order with adjustable time interval for picture change.

Answer (score 1):

IrfanView (https://www.irfanview.net/) is a free (as in beer) program that can do slide shows both in random order or according to a list. Viewing time can be set, too. Alternatively, use keyboard or mouse to advance pictures. 
Many years ago, before Beamer became available, I used IrfanView for my lectures.

Answer (score 0):

[XnViewMP](https://www.xnview.com/en/) will do what you need (random with longer times). In fact, most image cataloging applications will give you a nice slideshow on-demand. [ACDSee](https://www.acdsee.com/en/index) is another.

There's also a free versions of some of the better pay applications.

MS also says that they have some, but I've never tried any of them.